# how to make the Code return a list of [True, False]?

Tags: python, revitpythonshell

I'm trying to write a code on that return a list of boolean depending of the input.

I do the following:

```
User_inputs = IN[0]
OUT=[]

def input(User_inputs):

   if User_inputs == "FC":
      return [true,false]

   else:
      return [false,true]

OUT=input()
```

The code have only two possible inputs "FC" or "BF".

- if The chosen input is "FC" the ouput should be a list of boolean:

  ```
  index 1: True
  index 2: False
  ```
- if The chosen input is "BF" the ouput should be:

  ```
  index 1: False
  index 2: True
  ```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: `def input(User_inputs):return [User_inputs=="FC", User_inputs=="BF"]`

Comment: true and false are written `True` and `False` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
User_inputs = IN[0]
OUT=[]

def input(User_inputs):

   if User_inputs == "FC":
      return [True,False]

   else:
      return [False,True]

OUT=input(User_inputs)
```